# AXIS2-Parser already consumed

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm using axis2 1.5.4 and rampart 1.5.1. From time to time I get the following error :

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The parser is already consumed! 
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:792) 
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching(OMElementImpl.java:765) 
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeByPullStream(OMSerializerUtil.java:552) 
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:249) 
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) 
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:557) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400) 
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225) 
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438) 
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402) 
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229) 
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

The code I'm using to invoke the WS is:

```
EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(SERVICEOPERPREFIX + oper); 
ConfigurationContext ctx = ClsConfigurationContextFactory.getInstance(AXIS_REPOSITORY, AXIS_CONFIG).getContext(); 
ServiceClient sender = new ServiceClient(ctx, null);    
sender.engageModule("rampart"); 

this.options.setTo(targetEPR); 
this.options.setAction(OPERPREFIX + oper); 
this.options.setProperty(WSSHandlerConstants.OUTFLOW_SECURITY, getOutflowConfiguration(""+user)); 

sender.setOptions(this.options); 

MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager(); 
HttpConnectionManagerParams mParams = new HttpConnectionManagerParams(); 
mParams.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(MAXNUMCONNECTIONS);        
mParams.setConnectionTimeout(new Integer(OSBHTTPConnectionTimeout));     
mParams.setSoTimeout(new Integer(OSBHTTPReadTimeout)); 
httpConnectionManager.setParams(mParams); 

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpConnectionManager);     
sender.getOptions().setProperty("REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT", "true"); 
sender.getOptions().setProperty("CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT", httpClient); 

MessageContext requestMsgCtx = new MessageContext(); 
SOAPEnvelope inEnvelope = createSOAPEnvelope(); 

requestMsgCtx.setEnvelope(inEnvelope); 


OperationClient opClient= sender.createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);    
opClient.addMessageContext(requestMsgCtx); 

sender.cleanupTransport(); 
opClient.execute(true);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance